# ExtJS 3.4: How to show label in Nested Ext.form.Panel with column layout

Tags: extjs

I find it is impossible to show text label with column layout. I tried many configuration. Label fields still do not show up. Here is my code:

```
var contactPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel(
{             
       bodyStyle:"padding:5px",
       items:
       [
          {xtype:"fieldset",title:"Customer",html:"XXX COMPANY LIMITED"},
          {xtype:"fieldset",title:"Contact Person",items:[
            new Ext.Panel
            ({
              bodyStyle:"padding:0px 0px 0",labelAlign:'right',border:false,items:
              [{
                layout:"column",border:false,defaults:{border:false,defaults:{xfield:"form",defaultType:'textfield',anchor:'95%'}},
                items:[
                  {columnWidth:.05,html:"<span style='font-size:14px;position:absolute;'>English Name</span>"},
                  {columnWidth:.25,items:[new App.common.ArrayComboBox({width:120,fieldLabel: "Title", data:['Dr','Mr','Ms'], value:2})]},
                  {columnWidth:.35,items:[{width:220,fieldLabel:'Surname',xtype:'textfield',value:"Lau"}]},
                  {columnWidth:.35,items:[{fieldLabel:'Given Name',xtype:'textfield',value:"Alan"}]},
                  {columnWidth:.7,items:[{fieldLabel:'Customer Name',xtype:'textfield'}]},
                  {columnWidth:.5,items:[{fieldLabel:'Responsibility',xtype:'textfield'}]}
                ]
              }]
            })
          ]}
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are shown in panels of 'form' layout. Try to modify defaults of your inner panel to this (add layout: 'form'):

```
defaults:{border:false, layout: 'form',defaults:{xfield:"form",defaultType:'textfield',anchor:'95%'}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is shown in firefox now. But in IE 8, it still doesn't show up. Is it different?

Comment: Actually I experimented with this exactly on IE8 and it worked for me. It should not be different. Would you be able to reproduce this in fiddle?

Comment: Oh. Many thanks. I get it. Just typing mistake. I miss to add 'xfield:form'. It works now. Really thanks.